# SpecFlow documentation

Tags: specflow

Where can I read the SpecFlow documentation that tells me about the `[BeforeScenario]` and `[BeforeTestRun]` attributes and when they all run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some basic info here: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/

Comment: Thats the official page - and it's great. Here is a little post I wrote about it that tells a little more: http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/using-tags-in-specflow-features.html

Answer (score 4):

- `[BeforeTestRun]` and `[AfterTestRun]` represents the code that will be executed before and after all tests
- `[BeforeFeature]` and `[AfterFeature]` represents the code that will be executed before and after every feature
- `[BeforeScenario]` and `[AfterScenarion]` represents the code that will be executed before and after every scenario inside a feature
- `[BeforeScenarioBlock]` and `[AfterScenarioBlock]` represents the code that will be executed before and after every scenario block

Below you can see an example of a scenario with 3 blocks. The test will be executed before and after Given/When/Then blocks :

[Scenario Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkkFZ.png)

- `[BeforeScenarioStep]` and `[AfterScenarioStep]` represents the code that will be executed before and after every scenario step

Further information regarding using and setting up hooks in SpecFlow you can find below:

[SpecFlow - Using Hooks in your Tests](https://ralucasuditu-softwaretesting.blogspot.ro/2016/04/specflow-using-hooks-in-your-tests.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is also nice training on [pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com) SpecFlow Tips and Tricks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the spec flow getting started link.
https://specflow.org/getting-started/